# Finding the equation of a hyperbola that has two arbitrary intersecting lines as asymptotes

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

I have searched through math.stackexchange for related posts, but failed to either connect or transfer/map to my following mind-experiment:

> Suppose we are given two lines described by:
>   $3x+4y=2$ and further $-3x-2y=2$. They both intersect at $(-2,2)$. How can I compute the hyperbola using these two lines as the hyperbolas asymptotes?

A simple first naive approach with $$\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{a^2}-\frac{(y-y_0)^2}{b^2}=1$$ did not yield the expected result. It seems like the rotation is missing.

Thank you in advance for any hints and 
With best regards

Comment: there could be two hyperbolas with those asymptotes

Comment: Actually, there are infinitely-many hyperbolas with a given pair of asymptotes. Consider: $xy=k$, for any $k$, is a hyperbola with the coordinate axes as asymptotes.

Comment: It's worth noting that the product of the distances from a point on a hyperbola to the asymptotes is a constant. So, if you know the formula for the distance from a point to a line ...

Answer (score 4):

The equation of a hyperbola whose asymptotes have equations $3x+4y-2=0$ and $-3x-2y-2=0$ can be written as:
$$
(3x+4y-2)(-3x-2y-2)=k,
$$
where $k$ is a constant.
For every value of $k$ you'll get a different hyperbola. Given any point $P$ in the plane, you can choose $k$ such that the hyperbola passes through $P$.